# OPENJSON select value by dynamic key

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, open-json

```
data row 1 : 
{
    "30":{"status":0,"approval":"0","entrydate":"2023-01-30"},
    "26":{"status":0,"approval":"0","entrydate":"2023-01-30"}
}

data row 2 :
{
    "12":{"status":0,"approval":"0","entrydate":"2023-01-30"},
    "13":{"status":1,"approval":"20022-xxxx","entrydate":"2023-01-30"}
}

data row 3 :
{
    "20":{"status":1,"approval":"20022-xxxx","entrydate":"2023-01-30"},
    "24":{"status":1,"approval":"20022-xxxx","entrydate":"2023-01-30"}
}
```

How to select row data in a SQL Server database if `status=1` => `row 2`, `row 3` and if `status=0` => `row 1`, `row 2` because the json key is dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach is a combination of `OPENJSON()` and `JSON_VALUE()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM JsonTable
WHERE EXISTS(
   SELECT 1
   FROM OPENJSON(JsonColumn)
   WHERE JSON_VALUE([value], '$.status') = '0'
)
```